# Methods to have multiple Anti Virus installed on one machine

Tags: malware, virus, trojan

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro, Ideally I would like to have the top 5 Anti Virus installed but I am aware it is not advised as they can clash with each other.

I was wondering if there is a favoured way to do go about this, the first thing that comes to mind is have only 1 of the 5 anti virus running at any time to avoid the realtime conflicts between them.

My goal would be to have these Anti Virus scan my PC at different intervals each day.
Something like when its 11am Begin scan with Avast & disable other the other 4 Anti Virus, when its 1pm begin scan with Norton and disable the other 4 Anti Virus, etc...

Some Anti Virus pick up infections which others do not...

If this is a bad idea, please offer some suggestions.

Comment: This is very bad idea.

Comment: Some will identify other AV apps as viruses and remove them

Comment: I would look at Virus Total or [Herd Protect]( http://www.herdprotect.com/)

Comment: In order to prevent infection, modern antivirus packages tap into the operating system at quite a low level. One package doing this is ok, two packages trying to do this may work for an hour or two if you can get it to function, but somewhere along the line they're going to get into a gunfight over system resources and induce possible heavy collateral damage. One goodie is the McAfee scan that gets installed with Adoobie Flash (what are they smoking?) every so often either disabling the much better anti-malware/virus package you paid for, causing system performance problems or lockups.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to do this, the method with the least stability impact is to disable on-access protection, URL protection, email scanning, and everything else that scans at the time of potential infection.

Note that this is "method with least stability impact", not "best method".  By configuring your system this way, you ensure that you *will* be infected by any virus that enters your system.  You're counting on the antivirus software being able to remove the virus after it's been installed -- not a good idea, since viruses can and do disable antivirus software, and sometimes the only reliable way to remove an infection is a format-and-reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Installing multiple AVs is a very bad idea as the antiviruses will conflict with each other, will take unnecessary space on your hard drive and may cause system instability.I suggest you go with a well known antivirus that satisfy your needs and if ever you need to scan a file using multiple AV then use a free service like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)

Here is a [sample report](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/12f8e974d150f567493132e5f5516f1dfa0a704b7c34f3fae1c64a7c3c6a2357/analysis/1430076067/)

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive would become a major bottleneck plus all the conflicts between the separate AV's.  One AV should work, and then run the occasional Trend Micro's Housecall (or something equivalent) http://housecall.trendmicro.com/ will also download their latest updates and is a free scan.  Just don't click on popups and don't download sketchy files/games/movies/etc.. and you should be relatively good.